# Using N/record in Suitelet in Suitscript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to load a record using the n/record module in my Suitelet, but I'm getting the following error:

`org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "SALES_ORDER" from undefined`

```
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */

define(['./form', 'N/record'],
    function(form, record) {

        function onRequest(context) {

            if(context.request.method === 'GET'){
                var ratingForm = form.build(context);


                var customRec = record.load({
                    type: record.TYPE.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: 18
                });
```

This inside a form, and I'd like to load a record, and pre-populate any fields I can with the existing SALES_ORDER record.

Maybe I need to go about this in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `record.load` as follows

```
var customRec = record.load({
  type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  id: 18
});
```

You can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273205732.html) out for all the supported list of record types.

Comment: ha, guess I just needed another set of eyes. thanks